# C# EF code first comments for multiple item types - db design

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a dilemma and I don't know what will be the best way to do it.

I have 2 tables that store items of 2 types

- Tasks
- Items

Users can add comments to this items

So there will be another table called:

- Comments

As I have users, there is another table called:

- Users

Now how should I make my relation between these 4 tables?

Should I use only one comment table and store there comments for Tasks and Items or Tasks and Items should have each they own comments table?

Of course I need to link the Users to the comments table so that's one thing to be kept in mind. Basically can I use one comment table for multiple types or each type should have it's own comment?

Comment: How are tasks related to the other objects?

Comment: They are not. Completely separated.

Answer (score 0):

The EF Code first skeleton would look a little like this:

```
public class User{
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
}

public class Comment{
    public Guid CommentId {get;set;}
    public User Author {get;set;}
}

public class Item{
    public Guid ItemId {get;set;}
    public List<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}

public class Task{
    public Guid TaskId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: That should work, but I'd recommend decorating your classes and properties with attributes telling the database what's required, what's a key, and any other limitations you would normally have when creating the database objects manually.